# Auto expands numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I need a fast method for the following situation:

There is an array:

```
a = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3],
                [4, 5, 6]])
```

I want to expand it like

```
numpy.array([[1, 2, 3, 0],
             [4, 5, 6, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 9])
```

if I give something like

```
expand_and_put(a, (3, 4), 9)
```

This is for 3d array processing, therefore please consider what if a is an 3d array therefore the function takes a 3-item tuple in its second parameter.

Thanks

Comment: What's going on with that `9` there?

Comment: probably mistype, must be 0

Comment: Have you tried: `np.pad(a, (0, 1), 'constant')`? That should equally be applicable to a 3D array if you modify the pad with argument...

Comment: Sorry guys, 9 is the number to put in, therefore expand_and_put should have a third parameter. And thank you for notifying.

Comment: @jiz148 okay... so can you use pad like above and then `do result[-1, -1] = 9` (or whatever indexing is suitable) or something?

Comment: @JonClements This seems to be a good idea to use in the function.

Comment: @JonClements That worked. Thank you!

Comment: @jiz148 feel free to post a self answer with the solution as it could be of use to others in future. Thanks.

Comment: While using `pad` may be convenient, it is a good idea to understand how @bgmello's answer works.  Under the covers `pad` is doing something like that, or else doing several concatenates.  One way or other you have to initialize a target array of the right size, and write your array to it.